# Weekly check of the admin/performance/status report pages

Tags: drush

We run around 100 Drupal sites. I want to automate a weekly check that will scan all of the admin/performance/status report pages. I had a look at `drush status` but it doesn't give me the same information as the web interface does.

Has anyone done this and how did you go about it? Ideally I want to just email weekly to the developers team if there is an alert on any particular site

Comment: I think that the [Production check & Production monitor](https://www.drupal.org/project/prod_check) module provides all you need (and more), except for the emailing part.

Comment: I would recommend the [check_drupal](https://github.com/cytopia/check_drupal) Nagios plugin. I am using it myself for about 30 Drupal sites on different servers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use drush, `drush -n up` will show the available module updates.

Getting the status report (really "requirements" from the API's perspective) is a bit more convoluted, and can be output with

`drush php-eval 'include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . "/includes/install.inc"; drupal_load_updates(); print_r(module_invoke_all("requirements", "runtime"))'`

Other options are [Nagios](http://drupal.org/project/nagios), [Update Status Aggregator](http://drupal.org/project/update_status_aggregator), [Droptor](http://www.droptor.com/), or the [Acquia Network](http://acquia.com/products-services/acquia-network).

Comment: great, thanks for the response. I guess ideally I want to just be able to get the admin/reports/status page in curl if drush doesn't support this. Is drush capable of pulling certain pages via curl and passing on authentication? Or is there another way of doing this? Thanks alot for your help

Comment: I couldn't find an existing drush commind to invoke hook_requirements, but I've updated the answer with a workaround using php-eval.

Answer (score 2):

Drush now has the `core-requirements` command (whose aliases are `status-report` and `rq`). It's enough to run `drush core-requirements`.

For mass status checking, there is the Lumturio service which works through the [System Status](https://www.drupal.org/project/system_status) module.